# Is IOrderedQueryable.AsEnumerable() still ordered?

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, entity

`context.EntitySet.AsEnumerable().OrderBy()` returns an `IOrderedEnumerable` which is guaranteed to be ordered but it looks like the sorting is done client side.

`context.EntitySet.OrderBy().AsEnumerable()` preserves the expression as an `IOrderedQueryable` until it finally becomes an `IEnumerable`. I believe the ordering is done by the database in this case which is preferable. In some basic tests the output appears to still be ordered. Is ordering guaranteed even though `IOrderedQueryable.AsEnumerable()` only returns an `IEnumerable`?

Comment: ...why? What is the difference between IEnumerable and IOrderedEnumerable then?

Comment: @Kurian Methods like `ThenBy` need an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Calling `AsEnumerable` won't have some sort of "shuffling" function so I think it is a safe bet that it retains the ordering.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes even calling functions such as Concat keeps the ordering so I guess it's safe to assume the IEnumerable won't randomly get shuffled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed. `AsEnumerable` is only a simple forward-only wrapper (and `IOrderedEnumerable` is only a marker interface in fact).